# Issue with modifying string with python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need help with coming up with a way to modify:

```
expr = expr.replace(ip,"("+ip+".~"+ip+")")
```

in

```
for ip in input:
    expr = expr.replace(ip,"("+ip+".~"+ip+")")
```

The problem I am facing is that all instances of ip get replaced. So if `ip = "a1" then "a11","a12",....`all are replaced with the expression `"("+ip+".~"+ip+")"`instead of just the element "a1".
Here, expr is a string and ip is a list of strings.

What will be an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Please provide a sample snippet of input and the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `word` boundaries...

```
import re

expr = re.sub(r'\b' + ip + r'\b', "("+ip+".~"+ip+")", expr)
```

Comment: What if `re` is unavailable because, say, that's an assignment?

Comment: `re` unavailable? how?

Comment: @Brian You should avoid shadowing standard lib modules in your code, however if it's unavoidable you can `import re as something_else`